# jQuery Multiselect auto select

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I had this working at some point, as I had a question about this in the past that helped me, but now I lost the code, so I went back to my question and tried to get it working, and now it isn't...

Please someone help me as to why this isn't working anymore?

***CODE***

```
var valArr = [3, 4];
size = valArr.length;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    $("#secondary_group option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").
                                            attr("selected", 1);
    $("#secondary_group").multiselect("refresh");
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VXbLE/

What it's supposed to do, is select the option based on it's value, basically, you can read the code from the jsfiddle and figure that out.

I am a beginner in JavaScript/jQuery so I don't understand it completely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var valArr = [3, 4];
size = valArr.length; // detect array length
// looping over array
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    // $("#secondary_group option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']")
    // select the option with value match with the valArr
    // from the select with id=secondary_group and if match found
    // .attr("selected", 1);  make that option as default selected

    $("#secondary_group option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']")
                                            .attr("selected", 1);
}

// after selecting the options
// refresh the select using below code
// And this code should belong outside of
// above loop, because
// refreshing within loop will only 
// select last matched element
// not all matched

$("#secondary_group").multiselect("refresh");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VXbLE/2/)

Comment: Oh so my issue was that I was telling it to refresh in the loop?

Comment: @unlucky4ever yup, refresh should outside of loop